LINQ to SQL filter by multiple velues
My Model:
`class Person
{
   int ID { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
   IList<PersonRole> Roles { get; set; }
}

class PersonRole
{
   int ID { get; set; }
   int RoleID { get; set; }
   int PersonID { get; set; }
}`

My working filter:

    var result = context.Persons.Include( x => x.Roles ).Where( x => x.Roles != null && x.Roles.Any( y => y.RoleID == 1 ) ).ToList();


But I would like to have a little complex filter.
I would like filter by multiple person's roles:

var result = context.Persons.Include( x => x.Roles ).Where( x => ( new[] {1,2} ).All(r 
=> x.Roles != null && x.Roles.Select( y => y.RoleID ).Contains( r ) ) ).ToList();


or

var result = context.Persons.Include( x => x.Roles ).Where( x => x.Roles != null && 
x.Roles.Select( y => y.RoleID ).Intersect( new[] {1,2} ).Count() == 2 ).ToList();

LINQ to SQL cannot convert last 2 to SQL Query
Why?
